# Starting a Service throws an IllegalAccessException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, media-player

I have a `Service` which takes in an audio file and plays it with `MediaPlayer`. This is how I call my `Service`:

```
private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception {
    Intent music = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
    music.putExtra("paths", path);
    startService(music);
}
```

This is my `Service` class:

```
class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String musicFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle e = intent.getExtras();
        musicFile= e.getString("paths"); 
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicFile);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {             
            mediaPlayer.start();             
        } 
        return START_STICKY; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `Service` is never getting executed, the `Toast` is never shown, and the `MediaPlayer` does not play.

I declare my it in my manifest like this:

```
<service android:name=".MusicService" android:enabled="true"></service>
```

I get a force close error, and this `IllegalAccessException` in my logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service unjustentertainment.com.MusicService:
    java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
```

Comment: do you get an exception ? look in DDMS/LogCat if you get an exception that you can't understand post it here.

Comment: yea i got some that say unable to initiate service IllegalAccessException

Comment: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12): newInstance failed: Lunjustentertainment/com/MusicService; not accessible to Landroid/app/ActivityThread;
.086: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1252): Shutting down VM
11-26 12:07:46.086: WARN/dalvikvm(1252): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
 12:07:46.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12:07:46.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service unjustentertainment.com.MusicService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
11-26 12:07:46.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1252):

Comment: Add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exception you get is because the system could not init your service (call its constructor) because its not accessible.

As it says [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d06c3958773527a8):

> ...Make sure the class is 
>   declared public...

The class you posted is not public, so make it public.

Comment: This is a good idea now im getting this error though                                         

11-26 12:31:30.336: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1893): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service unjustentertainment.com.MusicService@44e83d70 with Intent { cmp=unjustentertainment.com/.MusicService }: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: provide full stack trace, where does the NullPointerExeption comes from?

Comment: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc unjustentertainment.com for service unjustentertainment.com/.MusicService: pid=1893 uid=10036 gids={1015}
2:31:30.286: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1893): Shutting down VM
 12:31:30.286: WARN/dalvikvm(1893): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12:31:30.336: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12:31:30.336: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1893): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service unjustentertainment.com.MusicService@44e83d70 with Intent { cmp=unjustentertainment.com/.MusicService }: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I figured it out now i just can't understand why my music won't start playing

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your class public. 
i.e.

```
 public class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
          MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
           String musicFile;
```

Comment: check my comments on the above answer

Comment: the stack trace your provided is partial. please provide a full stack trace. don't put it in a comment (there is not enough space there). edit your original post.